# node stripe deployment issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I made a react add with node backend using the stripe express checkout form, and passing the source and other data to the backend to subscribe users, but on production it does not work.
I have it on an ubunutu vps, and the app is served with nginx as a reverse proxy of localhost. but it is not working, i also added ssl certificate to the domain but I am getting an error now that says: 
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://localhost:8080/api”
on the server version in stripe test mode.
how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production it is required that you use SSL with Stripe. Your error is because you are trying to load or access `http://localhost:8080/api` from an originally `https` page. Stripe requires that **all** of your resources are loaded via `https`/SSL.

You also probably shouldn't be loading `localhost` in production. You should be using your actual hostname in production with `https`.

Let's say you load `https://example.com/` in your browser. And you want to make a call to your backend server that is running on `https://example.com/api`. Instead of specifying `localhost` you can just change the URL to be `/api` and that will automatically append the domain name `https://example.com` to the request. This only works for the same domains. If it's separate domains you have to specify the domain name in your request.

Comment: my app is on https, but it calls to the server, how to make it so that it accepts the localhost address?

Comment: @jhonathanmyers You can't use `localhost` in production. I mean MAYBE you can. But I can't think of ANY reason why you would. It makes 0 sense. Maybe you are expecting it to work, but chances are `localhost` in production doesn't work the way you are expecting. ALL calls to the server need to be `https`.

Comment: but how to call the server then?

Comment: @jhonathanmyers Just updated the answer. Basically you can either specify the domain name or IP address directly, or if it's the same domain name, you can just remove the domain and method and just specify the path.